# PDO Prepared statement not returning records

Tags: pdo, db2, odbc, prepared-statement

I'm able to connect to my DB2 database using PDO with an ODBC driver.  I am able to run queries and get results, but prepared statements return nothing (with no errors).

This code:

```
$pdo = new PDO("odbc:thingy","user","password");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM PROD.JMA3REP WHERE A3ANCD = 'DH 33-00'");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
dd ($rows);
```

returns one record.  Perfect.

This code:

```
$pdo = new PDO("odbc:thingy","user","password");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM PROD.JMA3REP WHERE A3ANCD = ?");
$stmt->execute(array('DH 33-00'));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
dd ($rows);
```

returns an empty array.

I've also tried using named parameters (...where A3ANCD=:id) and that hasn't worked either.

I've tried fiddling with all the PDO attributes and haven't had any luck.

The code runs fine on other ODBC setups -- what voodoo happens with a mix of unixODBC, DB2, and PDO to prevent this query from running? And how to I beat it into submission?

Comment: `id ?` - what's this?

Comment: A typo when I was cleaning up field names to be readable.  Fixed now.

Comment: Well, fix all other typos and you'll be set.

Comment: Try `$stmt->execute(array([1] => 5));`

Comment: @hjpotter92 WHAT FOR?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Since we generally start with `bindValue(1...`

Comment: @hjpotter92 Start from learning PDO *PLEASE*

Comment: @YourCommonSense see what I am talking about, you are not normal

Comment: @meda well, @YourCommonSense might be a bit heathen from time to time, but `execute(array([1]=>5));` *has* no sense... binding values and `?` parameters are not the same...

Comment: but anyway @J.T.Grimes those typos indicate the code in your question is not an actual copy paste from your script? how can we be sure you haven't fixed the problem b ytranscribing it? your code works...

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I know that, but there is no need to be mean/rude. Its not acceptable

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier - code is copied over with actual field names & values.  I know that the syntax is fine -- it's some sort of config with PDO/unixODBC/DB2 that's not working.

Comment: ...If it's something in the config, then I doubt we have sufficient information to help you - ie, what have you setup for the rest of the config?  Your first example query still contains a typo (the one that apparently returns results) - you don't have a closing apostrophe/single-quote.  What happens if you try to get two rows by doing a `UNION` with these two queries (and only providing a parameter for one of them)?  Or a join or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that pdo_odbc on a 64bit linux architecture is buggy and I'm not the first to run into this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18535989/1676

The solution appears to be using 32bit odbc drivers.