# PDO::bindValue() fails on query with nested SELECT

Tags: php, pdo

I am using an MSSQL database connected through ODBC.

When using `PDO::bindValue()` on a query that has a nested SELECT statement, it fails to bind values within the nested SELECT (no problem on the primary SELECT).
This is a piece of sample code that fails:

```
$stmt = $cmdb->prepare("SELECT ci.CI FROM dbo.cmdb_ci AS ci " .
                       "INNER JOIN dbo.cmdb_model AS m ON m.ModelID = ci.Modelid " .
                       "INNER JOIN dbo.cmdb_class AS c ON c.ClassID = m.Classid " .
                       "WHERE (c.ClassID = :classid) " .
                       "AND (ci.CI IN (SELECT ci2.CI " .
                                      "FROM dbo.cmdb_ci AS ci2 " .
                                      "INNER JOIN dbo.cmdb_ci_status AS st2 ON st2.CI = ci2.CI " .
                                      "WHERE st2.LocationID = :locationid))");
$stmt->bindValue("classid", 13);
$stmt->bindValue("locationid", 1011);
$stmt->execute();
if ($rows = $stmt->fetchAll())
    $stmt->closeCursor();
foreach ($rows as $row)
    echo $row["CI"];
```

The error I get is:

> SQLSTATE[22018]: Invalid character value for cast specification: 206 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Operand type clash: text is incompatible with int (SQLExecute[206] at /builddir/build/BUILD/php-5.4.16/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:254)

If I leave out the `bindValue()` for ":locationid" and insert '1011' directly into the query, the call completes without errors and with the correct results.

Is this a bug in PDO, or do I have to call bindValue() differently?

Comment: Is LocationID set to be int or text in your database?

Comment: How about `$stmt->bindValue("locationid", 1011,PDO::PARAM_INT);` as the error says,  you cast int with text.  bindValue with no PDO:PARAM_ becomes a string e.g. text.

Comment: LocationID is defined as an int.

Comment: Using explicit PDO::PARAM_INT does not have any effect.

Comment: its not `$stmt->bindValue("classid", 13);` its `$stmt->bindValue(":classid", 13);`

Comment: What operating system are you using? Can you share a sample schema with some data for testing? Which specific ODBC drivers are you using? There are a lot of bugs in PDO ODBC for ye olde PHP 5.4.16, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38255659), [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39088156), [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39044034), and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40116280). Your usage looks fine, but I'm not surprised it doesn't work. If you can provide the reproducible circumstances, preferably a docker image, then I'm sure someone can find a workaround for you.

Comment: I use PHP 5.4.16 on CentOS 7 (64 bits).

Comment: Do casting types. `$stmt->bindValue("locationid", (int)@$locationId);`

Comment: default 3rd parameter for the `bindValue` is `PDO::PARAM_STR`, so you have to specify the `PDO::PARAM_INT`

Comment: Did you test before using $stmt->bindValue ?

Comment: @Konstantin: I specify an integer value (1011) in the call to bindValue(), I do not use a variable. It would be silly to cast 1011 to an int, since it already is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532694/pdo-odbc-doesnt-work-whit-bind-values-nvarchar-and-text-are-incompatible-in-th in doubt, I'd move to the latest stable release of php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As (I read from comments) telling `bindValue` that the value passed is an integer **doesn't** solve the issue...

```
$stmt->bindValue( "locationid", 1011, PDO::PARAM_INT );
```

...I assume that for some reason ( [a **bug** in **pdo_odbc** ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532694/pdo-odbc-doesnt-work-whit-bind-values-nvarchar-and-text-are-incompatible-in-th) ) the parameter enters the query as a string no matter what you specify as third parameter on `bindValue`.

I would then suggest to work this around by casting the value to integer **in place** into the query.

On the last line:

```
"WHERE st2.LocationID = CAST( :locationid, int ) ))"
```

This is not very elegant but may be suitable until you find a fix/patch for pdo_odbc

---

**If even this doesn't work** there is an even more un-elegant solution (to be intended as temporary fix of course).

You wrote:

> If I leave out the bindValue() for ":locationid" and insert '1011' directly into the query, the call completes without errors and with the correct results.

So you may just place **location id** directly into the query.

Assuming **location id** is stored into `$locationId` then the last line of the query becomes:

```
"WHERE st2.LocationID = $locationId))");
```

As this is prone to sql-injection `$locationId` has to be sanitized (or verified) beforehand.

The value must be a positive integer so instead of escaping it I suggest an easier and bulletproof approach: check `$locationId` is made only of numbers...

```
if( ! ctype_digit( (string) $locationId ) ) {
    // location id is invalid
    // do not proceed !
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the Location ID is actually stored in MSSQL as a string and not an int? Does it work when you add quotes?
    $stmt->bindValue("locationid", "1011", PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: No, that does not work, since the LocationID value is defined as an INT (see above) so this would render it an invalid SQL statement.